# Is it always the case that an S-attributed and L-attributed SDD(syntax directed definition) will result in a dependency graph which is a DAG

Tags: compiler-construction, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm creating a compiler and i need to make sure that the dependency graph will never have cycles, so my question is will an S-attributed and L-attributed SDD always result in a DAG dependency graph, and if yes? how so?

Answer (score 1):

No.  One can inherit some attribute from the root to every leaf. No cycles in that.  One can synthesize a different attribute from all leaves ("count 1 child" for instance) and sum them on the way up the tree.  No cycles there.

So, a counterexample with no cycles.  So you don't *always* get cycles.

But yes, you can write an attribute grammar with cycles.  If an inherited attribute is computed by combining it with a synthesized one, and the synthesized attribute depends on the inherited one, you'll have a cycle in the dependency graph.

As a practical matter, you can simply ignore this case.  Anybody who writes such an AG will pay for it if they blindly compile and run it, when it gets stuck in a loop.  If she is any good, she'll figure out there's a cycle and break it and the problem goes away.      It is nicer if the tool constructs an abstract dependency graph and tells her.